# How do phase transitions occur in the solid phase?

Tags: phase, solid-state-chemistry

For example, how does graphite transform into diamond as pressure increases at a certain (adequate) temperature? I'm not sure if this is a great example to look at the bigger picture, so another example would be pure iron. At atmospheric pressure, as liquid iron cools down it solidifies to $\delta\text{-}\ce{Fe}$, with a *bcc* crystal structure. Further cooling down brings it to $\gamma\text{-}\ce{Fe}$, which has a *fcc*. Then, it keeps cooling down and it solidifies to $\alpha\text{-}\ce{Fe}$, again with a *bcc* structure. I don't really see how do the atoms physically rearrange to form the different crystal structures, neither do I see why would they jump back and forth between these. To add to this, I believe the difference between $\alpha$ and $\delta$ are their paramagnetic properties.

I guess the general question is, how do the atoms in the solid phase rearrange themselves by changes in pressure or temperature? (in contrast to, for example, a liquid-gas phase transition). And of course, why? What drives this change?

Comment: Magnetic properties have nothing to do with all this and are not the cause of difference between $\alpha$ and $\delta$. Indeed, $\alpha$ iron may or may not be ferromagnetic (dependent on temperature), while its crystal structure remains the same.

Comment: So they're both bcc, yet different?

Comment: In a way, they can be thought of as _not different at all_. Imagine one phase which is stable until certain temperature, then ceases to be stable, then becomes stable again, then melts.

Comment: Then why call them differently? And so, why would this happen?

Comment: Because one exists in one range of temperatures, and another exist in a different range, and never the twain shall meet. As to why, that's a very broad question, about as broad as chemistry itself. Solid phase structures are notoriously hard to predict.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone will be nice enough to give a broad but brief overview of what needs to be taken into consideration.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - well, the twain definitely can meet on binary phase diagrams, where it is quite clear that the two regions of bcc are the same since they are often connected. Now, your answer is correct - taking pure iron you see phase changes at different temperatures and each was given a name.

Comment: What do you know about thermodynamics of phase transitions, chemical potential etc?

Comment: Only what I learned in PChem as an undergrad. I'm a chemistry grad student, but mostly do OChem, so certainly it wouldn't be my strongest suit, yet I can probably follow some texts.

Answer (score 2):

Phase transitions in solids occur in the same manner as in liquids or gases, through nucleation and growth. Yes, those processes require atomic motion. Yet,atoms diffuse in solids all the time, through various mechanisms. While potentially slower, the thermodynamics of solid phase transitions are easily seen in calorimetry measurements for example.

Nucleation and growth of precipitates is a key part of many engineering alloys. On the other hand, some phase changes (like diamond to graphite) are very hard to make happen at near-human-tolerable temperatures.

The solid phase also sees the martensitic phase transitions, which are second-order diffusionless atomic rearrangements. The name comes from the martensite phase observed in steels. Shape memory alloys are another example of martensitic phases.

A classic materials science text would be 'Phase Transformations in Metals and Alloys", by D.A. Porter and K.E. Easterling. In my opinion, the second edition is vastly preferable to the more recent third edition where the changes mainly seemed to be reintroducing all the errors that were removed in the second edition (sigh).

Comment: The white allotrope of phosphorus transforms slowly to red even at STP, especially when exposed to light. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_phosphorus